# GDB showing incorrect function arguments on entry to C function

Tags: c, gdb, arguments

Debugging a C program with GDB I'm seeing the following (shortened):

```
(gdb)
1808            found = readOptionFromFile(options_file,...
(gdb) p options_file
$1 = (FILE *) 0xa812140
(gdb) s
readOptionFromFile (file=0x0, ...) at options.c:376
376 bool readOptionFromFile(FILE *file, ... {
(gdb) p file
$2 = (FILE *) 0x0
(gdb) n
378         int len, argc, i, c, isActiveSection, isActivePass, passn=0;
(gdb) p file
$3 = (FILE *) 0xa812140
(gdb)
```

Note that after stepping into the function GDB presents the arguments, particularly the formal argument `file`, as `0x0`, which is not what I'd expect since the actual argument `options_file` was printed to be 0xa812140 just before making the call. Even printing it at this point shows this incorrect value. However, after a `next` a subsequent `p` of it shows the value 0xa812140 again.

I can understand this from a technical perspective (function prologues, stack frames and such) but as a user I'd really want correct output from GDB. Is this known/expected behaviour or a bug?

I'm using `GNU gdb (Ubuntu 8.3-0ubuntu1) 8.3` on

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=19.10
DISTRIB_CODENAME=eoan
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 19.10"
```

(Actually on WSL)

Comment: `which obviously is wrong` why? Why is it wrong? Why is obvious? Please post an [MCVE].

Comment: shadowing going on perhaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although the [GCC manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) explicitly says:

```
-O0
    Reduce compilation time and make debugging produce the expected results.
    This is the default.
```

Of course, you could debate the "expected results" part...

But it also goes on to state

```
-Og
    Optimize debugging experience. -Og should be the optimization level of choice
    for the standard edit-compile-debug cycle, offering a reasonable level of
    optimization while maintaining fast compilation and a good debugging experience. 
    It is a better choice than -O0 for producing debuggable code because some
    compiler passes that collect debug information are disabled at -O0.
```

Using `-Og` should solve the issue.

UPDATE: I found that the best option for debugging might often actually be `-O0` since `-Og` allows for many variables to be optimized out because of the [as-if rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if). There is [an issue about this](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla//show_bug.cgi?id=78685) from 2016.

Comment: It's likely that this too is related to WSL in some way, as I've never had this problem with -O0 on standard Linux, but saw it today on WSL.